# Slice "colon operator" nomenclature

Tags: python, terminology

Is the colon `:`, when used in slices in Python, called anything special? Other than, say, the slightly medicinal sounding *"colon operator"*?

```
x = s[:5]
    # ^ this character
```

Comment: you could call it slice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard it referred to as anything in particular, and it's not named in [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings). It's incorrect to call it an operator, though; it's just a delimiter for the bounds and stride.

Comment: It's normally just called a colon. I guess you could call it a "slice colon" if you want to be specific. It's not actually an operator, it's a [delimiter](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?delimiters#delimiters).

Comment: Maybe `slice delimiter`.

Answer (score 1):

I researched the History of Python blog written by Python's creator and they only ever seem to refer to it as a colon. Example reference: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2011/07/karin-dewar-indentation-and-colon.html

Comment: That page doesn't talk about slicing though, it's a different usage of the colon. Is there another page that talks about the slice syntax? I couldn't find one from a quick search.

Answer (score -1):

Delimiter, I hereby name you `:` colonic slice

Comment: It's not a slice itself though, it's part of the slice syntax.